# Server side rendering React components that loads state through Ajax

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering

I'm struggling to make my component work on both client and server side.

This is the code for my component:

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            title: props.params.title,
            message: props.params.message
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get-message",
            success: function (result) {
                this.setState({
                    title: result.title,
                    message: result.message
                });
            }.bind(this),
            cache: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
                <h3>{this.state.message}</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It works ok. When it gets rendered though client side, it shows both `h2` and `h3` empty and then they are filled when the ajax call returns.

When it gets rendered though the server, I already get those props filled and the html sent to the client is already completed and don't need anything extra.

The problem is that when it gets rendered on the server, I get the error message on the client:

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. [...]
```

It then calls the ajax method again and re-renders everything.

So how should I handle such case? Is there a way to tell React that this component was rendered on the server accept it and not call the `componentDidMount` method?

Comment: Do you want the SERVER side rendering make the ajax call? so the CLIENT will have the FINAL markup?

Comment: the ajax call would call a method available on the server side as well, so no ajax call on the server. The accepted answer did what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to work with this is by using global state. You could serialize a JS object at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, containing the state calculated on the server side.

```
<script>globalState={MyFeature: {title: 'foo'}};</script>
```

Then use that state (or a branch of it) as default for your components.

e.g.

```
if (globalState.MyFeature.title) {
    this.setState({ title: globalState.MyFeature.title });
} else {
    $.ajax(/* ... */);
}
```

Obviously you can use Redux to manage your global state nicely, but you don't really *need* to. However, there are many useful packages available that will help you streamline this process.

- [react router redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux)
- [redux-async-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-async-connect)
- [serialize-javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript) - you can use this one without redux